# Navigate input fields with "Next" key on Firefox on Android

Tags: android, html, firefox, accessibility

I have a simple form element with a few inputs. On Chrome Android, I can navigate to the next field with the virtual keyboard using the "next" key. On Firefox Android, that key is not displayed in the virtual keyboard.

How do I enable that "Next" key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question. This turned out to be a bug on Firefox Android.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=990473